# Angular material 2 drag and drop orientation both directions

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-cdk

Is it possible to make the orientation to sort in both directions for cdk-drag and drop? I am trying to make a dashboard that looks like grafana. That sorts the dragable items in both directions. And does anyone have any angular resize handler library to recommend?

Example- [a link](https://play.grafana.org/d/000000012/grafana-play-home?orgId=1&from=1537942300514&to=1537943439675)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't support this yet. 
Refer to: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/13372